# How to delete duplicate rows including the first row as well?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, sql-delete

I have a table with columns

```
Car   |   User  |  Location  |  Time  |  Type
```

I want to delete all rows that have duplicates, leaving only rows that are distinct based on the `car, user, location, time` columns

For example:

```
Car   |   User  |  Location  |         Time          |  Type
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |    Ben  |   Chicago  |  2022-02-12 03:12:45  |   OUT        //should be deleted
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |    Ben  |   Chicago  |  2022-02-12 03:12:45  |   IN         //should be deleted
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  2   |    Sam  |  New York  |  2022-02-12 04:42:45  |   OUT        //should be kept
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |    Ben  |   Chicago  |  2022-02-12 04:50:00  |   OUT        //should be kept
```

To make it easier for help

```
CREATE TABLE rent_logs (
  car varchar(30),
  user varchar(30),
  location varchar(30),
  time datetime,
  type varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO rent_logs ( car, user, location, time, type ) 
VALUES ( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago','2022-02-12 03:12:45',  'OUT' ), 
( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago',' 2022-02-12 03:12:45',  'IN' ), 
( 2, 'Sam', 'New york','2022-02-12 04:42:45',  'OUT' ), 
( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago','2022-02-12 04:50:00',  'OUT' ), 
( 2, 'Sam', 'New york','2022-02-12 07:32:12 ',  'IN' ), 
( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago','22022-02-12 08:18:45',  'IN' ), 
( 3, 'Mia', 'Chicago','2022-02-12 09:12:43',  'OUT' ), 
( 1, 'Ben', 'Chicago','2022-02-12 09:27:23',  'IN' )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the table to a query that aggregates in `rent_logs` and returns all the rows with duplicates:

```
DELETE r
FROM rent_logs r
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT car, user, location, time
  FROM rent_logs
  GROUP BY car, user, location, time
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t ON (t.car, t.user, t.location, t.time) = (r.car, r.user, r.location, r.time);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8bd20a0f881ced5f12dafcb04c9a896).

Comment: just need to pay attention here that this only works for rows that do not have duplication in the TIME column (to process them, you will have to add row_number)

Comment: @Jesusbrother *this only works for rows that do not have duplication in the TIME* what are you talking about?

Comment: check this one, 2 more rows added as an example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=454a28f846dd1b7ea466703071fc70cf

Comment: @Jesusbrother the requirement is: *...leaving only rows that are distinct based on the (car, user, location, time) columns* the column type is irrelevant.

Comment: @forpas this seems to work as expected, thank you very much :) Is there any way I can transform this into a SELECT query? As in selecting only the rows that don't have duplicates, instead of deleting the ones that do?

Comment: @SerdaShehu check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d1cd585806adda1f62b17cd93402a72

Comment: @SerdaShehu or better this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b49c7b09e10fbe49a8fe66a42024af3